# How to exclude leading single or double quotes from regex expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

How can I just get the target word without the leading and trailing characters of single or double quote? Currently the expression below matches all. I tried inserting [^'] but it did not work.

```
[\b(?i)Test\b]

test - match
Test - match
TEST - match
'test' - I do not want this to match
"test" - I do not want this to match
```

Comment: do you want to match `test` from `'test'`?

Comment: i want to match test not 'test' in a paragraph and ignore casing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
(^|[^'"])test([^'"]|$)
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working plus I need to maintain boundaries \b